# Neo4j 2.2 spatial withindistance label issue

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

Just started playing around with Neo4j 2.2. Awesome work! Unfortunately I ran in some problem using spatial-0.14-neo4j-2.2.0-M02 :( In my application I have a query which fetches the nearest users:

```
START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[42.0,1.0, 1000.0]') WHERE n:User RETURN n;
```

After updating to the latest version above query does not seem to care about label anymore and I get all nodes which has lat/lon and are added to the spatial layer back. Anyone else who have experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation seems to be correct, I could reproduce it. It seems that the `WHERE` directly following a spatial index query is not honored.

However there is an easy workaround by introducing a `WITH`:

```
START n=node:geom('withinDistance:[42.0,1.0, 1000.0]') 
WITH n 
WHERE n:User 
RETURN n;
```

Please check if that works. Please file a bug report at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new.

Comment: Many thanks Stefan!! The workaround fixes my problem and I have now filed a bug report.